# Visual Studio 2019 can't target framework which is already installed on my PC

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8

I am trying to target framework which already installed on my PC without success. This when creating new simple console project:

[image]

But when I try to install for example 4.8 framework it says that this framework is already installed:

[image]

Also in the registry, I can have 4 (but I don't see 5):

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: There is a rash of devs picking the wrong project template to get started.  You need "Console App (.NET Framework)", that one lets you target 4.8.  The one you got now is named "Console App (.NET)", it can only target .NET Core versions (like .NET5).

Comment: this is what visual studio listed when i create new project

Answer (score 0):

For VS (and other developer tools) to work you need the *Developer Pack* for that version of .NET.

This is a different download to the normal, runtime only, installer.